# android Cant play video in Built-in player

Tags: android, video

i have video from url .. and i cant play this video .

> File Format:
>       MP4
>       mp4
>       Duration:
>       00:13:33
>       00:13:33
>       Bit Rate:
>       1036K
>       1127K
>       File Size:
>       100.50 MB
>       105.59 MB
>
> ```
> Video Stream#1
>
>
> Video Codec:
> h264
> h264
> Video Bitrate:
> 935K
> 935K
> Video Size:
> 700x394
> 700x396
> Aspect Ratio:
> 1.78:1
> 1.77:1
> Frame Rate:
> 30.00fps
> 30.00fps
> Audio Stream#1
>
>
> Audio Codec:
> mpeg4aac
> mpeg4aac
> Audio Bitrate:
> 95K
> 192K
> Channels:
> 1
> 2
> Sample Rate:
> 44100
> 44100
> ```

when i convert it with same specs its then it start to play video  have any idea what is issue. 
[image: image to show profile]

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the problem is that the source has something beyond baseline profile (see http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

Comment: i just notice that it can might be issue audio channels becouse source have 1 audio channale

Comment: I don't believe there may be a problem playing audio with 1 channel. If you have the source file available for download, I could look at it.

Comment: `bin/ffmpeg -debug bugs -i Feedback.mp4 -vn qq.mp3` crashes with words: `[aac @ 0000000001C839D0] err{or,}_recognition separate: 1; 1
[aac @ 0000000001C839D0] err{or,}_recognition combined: 1; 65537
[aac @ 0000000001C839D0] Unsupported bit depth: 0`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16488/discussion-between-nomee-tec-and-alex-cohn)